# Is there a way to lazy unpack an infinite generator?

Tags: python, generator

In this situation, I want to define some IDs with increasing integer:

```py
id_a, id_b, id_c = range(3)
```

That's OK for few IDs.
But if there were many IDs, and will be more in future. It's too tedious to change the range(n) number for every time I add a new ID.
So, I make an infinite generator for all new IDs:

```py
def make_id():
    c_id = 0
    while True:
        yield c_id
        c_id += 1
```

Or, use the count straightly:

```py
from itertools import count
make_id = count
```

Then, I wish I can define any number of IDs like this:

```py
id_a, id_b, id_c, id_d, id_e = make_id()
```

But, it cause an error "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

BTW, it's OK in javascript:

```js
let make_id = function *() {
    let c_id = 0;
    while(true) {
        yield c_id++;
    }
};

const [id_a, id_b, id_c, id_d, id_e] = make_id();
```

So, is there a way to lazy unpack an infinite generator in this situation in python?

===== Updated =====

In my project in javascript, I do something lie this:

```js
const CFG_DBG = true;

let gen_sym = function *() {
    let cur = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(CFG_DBG) {
            yield 'private_attr_' + (cur++).toString();
        } else {
            yield Symbol();
        }
    }
};

let [
    PRIVATE_ATTR_A, PRIVATE_ATTR_B,
] = gen_sym();

let some_obj = {
    "public_attr_a": "this is public a",
    [PRIVATE_ATTR_A]: "you shouldn't read this",
};

let some_other_obj = {
    [PRIVATE_ATTR_B]: "you shouldn't read this too",
};
```

It can ensure the private attribute that can not be access in release version.

So, I want do something like this in python.
I know the "__private_attr" name, but it can still be access with a prefix.

Comment: Have you considered https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html ?

Comment: @yatu that is good advice, although, the question is more general than taht. The fact that it involves IDs is just a toy example

Comment: Well I'm not sure, my feeling is that indeed that your answer *does* answer the question, but OPs way to go about this isn't right at all. This is not a good idea to generate new ids @juanpa

Comment: Yes, that IDs generator is just an example. I just want to unpack an infinite generator to variables stand alone in namespace, not to a list or something like that.

Comment: I think the premise is kind of misleading (just guessing a bit here). If you have some values defined in variables and you find yourself adding variables to store more of those values, you should probably then consider a list. This would make it much easier to handle (you add one id by increasing the size of the list). If you need a named reference a dictionary could also work. Without knowing more about the context, this looks like a bit of bad design to me.

Comment: It also seems a bit odd to want to assign all those to new variables rather than a some iterable? If you'll only be keeping some id, why not have them in say, a list which you could easily index?

Comment: @yatu  I update my application situation. I think a named variable is more readable than a list with an index for attribute key.

Comment: Of course, in your original example, `id_a = range(1)` or `id_a = make_id()` will not give you what you want, namely assigning 0 to id_a. It will only assign a range object or generator function to id_a. So the notation only works for two or more ids.

Answer (score 3):

Python is, as a rule, much stricter about these sorts of things. You can do it only with an iterable with the exact size. If the iterable were finite, you *could* use:

```
a, b, c, *rest = iterable
```

But this will loop forever with an infinite iterable. And of course, it consumes the entire iterable, which is not what you want. One thing you can do is:

```
from itertools import islice, count

make_id = count()

id_a, id_b, id_c = islice(make_id, 3)

# do some stuff

id_d, id_e = islice(make_id, 2)
```

But you still have to be explicit about the size of the iterator.

Comment: "But this will loop forever with an infinite iterable. " True, but I'm wondering why that is. Why they didn't make it lazy.

Comment: I bet there's the answer in the PEP that introduced that, I'll look it up someday.